# Magento 2 run php bin/magento without command line

Tags: magento2, bin-magento

I have Magento 2 store and I need to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`. But the problem is that client has just a basic webhosting, so there is no command line.

Is it possible to create php file that will execute this command, and then I will just open it in browser to run it?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this question is duplicate as the `already answered` one has different context.

Answer (score 2):

> Yes you can do it by using php file. Create a php file on root folder and paste this code.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['command_name'])){
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r(system('/usr/bin/php '.$_POST['command_name']));
}

?>
<form action="" method="post">
 <label>Command</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i>php</i>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="command_name" value=""/>
 <button name="submit" type="submit">Run</button>
</form>
```

> Change "/usr/bin/php " with your server php path.
>
> Then use commands like. bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: Considering security, this is about the worst thing you can do - making shell (php) commands accessable via an html form

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in a php file. And run this file in browser.

```
<?php

print_r(system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade'));
```

Comment: Would a hosting company allow system function?